# For a key-value pair with simple values, is n't a relational database as good as a No-SQL database such as Redis?

Tags: sql, redis, nosql, relational-database, key-value

Consider a key value pair in which both keys and values are strings. eg..
A key value pair that maps from long URL to short URL and vice-versa. 
Long URL->Short URL. 
A main advantage of no-SQL is that there are no table joins required as the entire data(that is spread across lot of tables in relational database) is stored as one document(Couchbase) or one value(Redis). In this case, our value is a simple String and not some object that is spread across multiple tables.

So, no joins or multiple table look-ups involved here and a no-SQL database is not superior here. A relational database will be equally good. 
Or even for simple values, do no-SQL databases(eg. Redis which is a key-value pair store) outperform relational databases?

Answer (score 0):

I think your general understanding of the issue is correct, although NoSQL vendors would probably claim that they also offer other benefits—mainly "scale out [at a magnitude only possible with eventual consistency]".

They would probably not tell you that many SQL databases can also scale out by some extend (often by means of replication but there are also more advanced concepts). However, as most SQL databases honor the strict consistency model of SQL, the scale out capabilities are typically limited to the extend that is possible without giving up consistency. But even there, exceptions exist—e.g. asynchrosnus replication (for read only load), "master-master" replication (for read/write load).

Regarding your original question (normalization, joins) I'd also like to add that SQL database do **not** require you to split your data into individual columns or spread them across tables. They **offer** this way do to things, but they also allow you to store a JSON document in a single column essentialy expanding your argument to all document stores.

If you can spare 15 minutes, have a look at this video recording of a talk I gave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swR33jIhW8Q

Comment: Q1) SQL databases allowing to store JSON document ? Is n't this a recent addition? Probably, it was incorporated hastily not to lose ground to noSQL databases.
Q2) My original question - If we are storing a simple key and a simple value and no relations are involved, SQL and noSQL databases are equally good.One cannot claim superiority over the other. So, do you agree with this?

Comment: Q) If SQL databases too can store JSON, how can noSQL databases claim superiority in that aspect? 
One argument often given in favor of No SQL is -"NoSQL can store JSON..data in document form...we can keep all data in one JSON or in some document(eg. Couchbase stores documents) instead of spreading across multiple tables"

Comment: That is a nice video. Looks like you are a DB expert. Can you answer the above questions asked by me? That will help me get a clearer picture. 
It would be great if you can take a stab at this question too - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742813/how-to-handle-concurrent-inserts-into-db-causing-violation-of-a-rule-for-the-rec