# How to handle concurrent inserts into DB causing violation of a rule for the records in the database?

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, insert, locking

We have a CARD table that stores card number and user account number. Only a max of two users can share the same card. This constraint is not implemented as an SQL constraint on the table but is imposed in the code in the following way.

When a user tries to add a card -

1. check whether the card number already exists in the DB. Done by querying the table with the card number.
2. If no records, it means it is a new card. Add a record.
3. If there are already records - 
   if the no. of records is less than 2 - add a record in the table for this user. <same card number,this user account number>
   if it is equal to 2 - the limit is reached and we cannot add this card to this user. So, the code will throw an error.

Now the problem:

Assume that 100 users are trying to add the same card at the same time. This card did not exist in DB before. The following will happen.
100 requests(one request for each user) are processed in 100 threads. Each thread will see that the card number is not present in the table -> the no. of users who added this card is 0 which is less than the limit.i.e, 2 . So, each thread will try to insert a record into the table. In the end, we will have 100 users in the table sharing the same card.

```
user 1,card number  - thread 1
user 2,same card number - thread 2
user 3, same card number - thread 3.
......
....
user 100, same card number - thread 100
```

We wanted only a max of 2 users to share the card but our shared card limit is broken now. How to tackle this scenario?

One obvious answer is synchronization of inserting the record in the DB. But,it leads to the following problem.

Assume 100 users are trying to add 100 different card numbers. If we synchronize insert operation, when one request tries to insert a record into the table, all other requests will be kept waiting->Response time for the API 
takes a heavy beating. But, in this case, there is no need to do it because the user,card Number combination is different for every request. So, that option is ruled out. What options are we left with now?

Comment: Create code segment block logic. Update record via transaction - `Update segmentblocktable setsomeField = 1 where segmentId = 'xxx'`. This will hold all requests that hit this record. In the next statement you do your check and either accept a card or reject. This code will be ok, if you have 1 DB and app can be desktop or web, all will act the same

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . Oracle. Added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is called Write Skew.

In principle, SERIALIZEABLE transaction isolation takes care of this, [**but** not in Oracle DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation#Terminology). Oracle only provide snapshot isolation, even when you ask for SERIALIZABLE.

In Oracle, pretty much the only relyable solution is to use some kind of locking. This doesn't necessarily need to be a lock on a table row, you can also use advisory locks via DBMS_LOCK for that.

Comment: SERIALIZEABLE - If two transactions are trying to update the same column in the same row at the same time, one will gain access to the row, will acquire a lock and the other will have to wait. After the lock is released, what will happen when the second transaction tries to update the value? Will it get an error? I think that should be the case.

Comment: @PraveenNvs You are only thinking about locks, but there are also other techniques to ensure serializability (MVCC - snapshots). If your TX was only about writes, there would be no conflict. But you are also doing reads, this is what causes the inconsitency. SERIALIZEABLE makes sure (except in Oracle) that only transactions that would have been possible when executed sequencially can be commited.

Comment: got it . just curious to know what the fate of the second transaction will be . 
1. If the serializability is implemented using locks(looks like multiple locking mechanisms are available for this) - will the second transaction get an error if it tries to update the value after the lock is released?
2. Is this behaviour dependent on the DB?

Comment: 1. No, if the update is the only statement in this transaction; 2 I don't think so, if the update is the only statement in the transaction ;)

Comment: so, the second transaction will execute its update..what if there is a read or read and update in the second transaction ? Can that result in error?

Comment: 2.  I think in case of snapshot isolation , it will result in an error because this is what will happen there -
Two transactions are trying to update a value. Each transaction takes a snapshot of the DB. It will try to update only if the value in the snapshot has not changed (one way to check this is using timestamps). So, when the second transaction does update, it internally re-reads the data and sees that the snapshot got changed as the first transaction updated the value. -> therefore, the second transaction will be aborted. Am I correct?

Comment: Here is what Oracle does - 
"Oracle generates an error when a serializable transaction tries to update or delete data modified by a transaction that commits after the serializable transaction began:

ORA-08177: Cannot serialize access for this transaction " . In oracle's language,serializibility means snapshot isolation. so,this seems to be the behaviour for Oracle.

Comment: For a bigger picture, have a look at these slides: https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/sql-transactions-what-they-are-good-for-and-how-they-work?ref=https://winand.at/sql-slides-for-developers . The comments here are not the place to discuss this.

Comment: I saw your name  in this article - https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-serializable-is-not-serializable/ today . Amazing Looks like it is the same link mentioned there ..!

Comment: @ Markus Winand -  Read all the slides. Liked it. Can you take a stab at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811167/how-is-oracle-acid-compliant-when-it-does-not-honour-isolation-property-fully ?