# How is Oracle ACID compliant when it does not honour 'isolation' property fully?

Tags: sql, transactions, rdbms, isolation-level, acid

Claim: Oracle does not honour isolation property in ACID properties.
As per [Wikipedia page on ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation)

> "Isolation ensures that concurrent execution of transactions leaves the database in the same state that would have been obtained if the transactions were executed sequentially."

This can happen only if the transactions are serializable. Yes, Oracle has a transaction level called Serializable but it is not true serializability and is only snapshot isolation.

Read https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-serializable-is-not-serializable/
An excerpt from Wiki page of Snapshot isolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation)

> "In spite of its distinction from serializability, snapshot isolation is sometimes referred to as serializable by Oracle".

There are weaker isolation levels but they are not sufficient to guarantee that the sequence of transactions would lead to the outcome that would be obtained if they were executed sequentially. To guarantee it, serializability is a must.

Q1) Since Oracle does not provide it (its serializaibility is not a true one), it does not honor isolation 100 percent. How can then it be called ACID compliant?

Q2) Looks like Oracle was treated here leniently with regard to isolation. Is this leniency extended to other databases as well?

Q3) If we take an unforgiving stance and say (isolation means 100 percent isolation - no less is accepted), won't Oracle's claim of being ACID compliant fall to pieces? What about other relational databases? Will they be able to make the cut or will they fall short like Oracle?

Comment: Postgres implements a true serializable isolation level. But in my understanding ACID is not (only) about providing a serialization isolation level. To support the `A` and the `I` - `read committed` is already enough I think.

Comment: Your questions are predicated on misunderstandings. The ACID acronym doesn't have a precise meaning. Read the paper in which it appeared--they just start with the 4 items as mere informal highlights for understanding & summarizing implementation of serializable schedules, ie implementing concurrent transactions that act as if they were serialized, ie implementing what SQL means by SERIALIZABLE. The Wikipedia ACID page is just another unjustified parroting of misrepresentations of the paper. Oracle SERIALIZABLE is not "serializable" & claims it is "ACID compliant" are specious.

Comment: What "leniency"? Anybody can claim anything, there's no authority granting permission to misrepresent or mislead. What "Oracle's claim of being ACID compliant"? Please give a quote. PS Please ask one question per question.  Please don't ask for lists of outside resources or their properties. Please research before considering asking a question. What have you found to answer your own (on-topic) questions? See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy- Only after doing thorough research, I ask a question here. This is the last resort. My question was not about just Oracle. It is about relational databases in general.(Are they really ACID compliant?). We cannot ask many questions in the comments section and hence, I ask all of them in the post.
What "Oracle's claim of being ACID compliant"? Please give a quote - Does that mean that Oracle is not ACID compliant? But, many relational databases (I think including Oracle) proudly wear the badge of ACID compliance. ACID is closely associated with RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has SERIALIZABLE in addition to SNAPSHOT.  But, at least in SQL Server, for most practical purposes SERIALIZABLE is useless, as it's too expensive, and not really effective.  And you use special constructs for the few transactions that actually need to be serialized (ie run one-at-a-time).

SERIALIZABLE is to expensive because transaction ordering is accomplished by some combination eliminating concurrency, and by generating run-time failures (deadlocks).  Both of which are very expensive and troublesome.

SERIALIZABLE is not really effective, because doesn't actually accomplish complete transaction isolation.  To do so would require every transactions to exclusively lock all data it reads, to prevent two transactions from reading the same data, and then writing.
The classic example is where two sessions run

```
SELECT salary FROM emp where id = 1
```

and then, compute a new value based on the existing in the client, and then

```
UPDATE emp set salary = :newSalary
```

The only way to make this work right is to place an exclusive lock on the first read, so a second session can't read too.

In Oracle this is accomplished with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, and in SQL Server with an UPDLOCK hint.  Or with an explicit "application lock", Oracle's DMBS_LOCK, or SQL Server's sp_getapplock.

Comment: The overhead of the SSI ("Serializable Snapshot Isolation") depends on the implementation, it's not something inherent with the principle. In Postgres for example the overhead of SSI over just "Snapshot Isolation" ("repeatable read") is very low

Comment: Read  https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-serializable-is-not-serializable/ . Looks like Postgres is providing serializability automatically which Oracle cannot . "It seems that only PostgreSQL (version >= 9.1) is able to guarantee true serializability without locking."

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft - Can you answer Q3 in my post? Just for the sake of argument, let us assume that we want 100 percent isolation and won't take anything less than that.
"SERIALIZABLE is not really effective, because doesn't actually accomplish complete transaction isolation." - But, that is the meaning of serializable. Is n't it? Oracle's serializable may not accomplish it but others like Postgres seem to be doing it. Read my above comment.

Comment: Postgres will still abort transactions if it detects update anomalies.  It may have a better implementation of SERIALIZABILE, in the sense that it prevents more anomalies with less disruption.  But the cost is still there.